# Bitbucket repo clone or download?

Tags: git, repository, clone, bitbucket

Is using Download repository option equivalent to using git clone?

**git clone url_of_repo**

what is the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, download is more [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

You end up with an archive of the current HEAD (meaning no history).
You can also pick-up an archive from a tag commit, or a branch HEAD. Again: no history.

[`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) will get you the repo with its full history.